# Bundler binstubs directory is in the current directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

In my project's staging environment I receive the following warning when I cd into the project directory:

> The bundler binstubs directory is in the current directory, which may be unsafe.
>   Consider using rubygems-bundler instead => https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler
>   Remove the BUNDLE_BIN line from .bundle/config to disable this prompt.
>   Are you sure you want to add the bundler binstubs directory to the path?

I haven't yet installed the rubygems-bundler gem as I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of the warning without doing so.  If using the gem is necessary, are there any other issues I'd need to be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just reconfigure bundler to not use the root project directory for binstubs, assuming you don't need that for anything, by removing that line from `.bundle/config`.